# Recursive calls using reassigned parameter in expression bodied member

Tags: c#

I think this recursive pattern would be kinda neat to implement, but I'm having trouble to do so. Is it somehow possible to re-assign a passed parameter in a expression bodied member? I think that's the limitation that i'm hitting here. According to MSDN on EBM it sais:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expression can be used as a statement

Which I am fulfilling, so I'm not sure as to why this is not working.

This is a working version of what I want to achieve:

```
List<int> data = new List<int>
{
    120183,
    105169,
    58942
};
int result = 0;
int calc(int a) => result += a;
foreach(int m in data)
{
    int res = m;
    while ((res / 3) - 2 > 0)
    {
        calc(res = res / 3 - 2);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine($"{result}");
```

Now I instead want to do the same thing, but **within** an expression bodied member.
I think these versions should be equivalent to each other. What am I missing?

```
List<int> data = new List<int>
{
    120183,
    105169,
    58942
};

int result = 0;
int calc(int a) => result += (a / 3 - 2) > 0 ? calc(a = a / 3 - 2) : 0;
data.ForEach(x => calc(x));

Console.WriteLine($"{result}");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in the recursive implementation is that it never actually adds a non-zero value to `result`. Whenever `(a / 3 - 2)` is greater than 0, calc is recursively invoked with the new value `(a / 3 - 2)` once the value passed to `calc` diminishes to be less than or equal to 0 a value of 0 is returned, which the parent call adds to `result` and subsequently returns the new value of `result` to the parent. So the net result is just `result += (result += (result += 0)))`.

If you want to use an expression bodied function for `calc`, instead of assigning result within calc, declare a version of calc that simply performs the calculation:

```
int calc(int a) => (a / 3 - 2) > 0 ? ((a / 3 - 2) + calc(a / 3 - 2)) : 0;
```

And then perform the assignment within your `ForEach` function:

```
data.ForEach(x => { result += calc(x) });
```

Comment: Thank you! Great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Look at what `calc` returns. In your second case, it returns either `calc(a = a / 3 - 2)` or `0`. Subsequent calls to `calc` result in the same thing, meaning that unltimately this evaluates to 0. `calc` can then be simplified to `int calc(int a) => result +=0`.

This should yield the correct result.

```
int calc(int a) 
{
    if ((a / 3 - 2) > 0)
    {
        result += (a / 3 - 2);
        return calc(a = a / 3 - 2);
    }
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: He wants the expression body member